# After enabling ivy-mode, `dired-create-directory' does not allow me to choose an entry not in the completion list

Tags: dired, ivy

Is there any way to allow me to type in a new dir name that is not in the completion list generated by ivy-mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

There are 2 cases. The name you want to create doesn't match anything in the completion list, or when it does.

When it doesn't, you can just type in the name and press enter.

If it does match, then pressing enter will get ivy to expand the name to the completion. Here you want to call `ivy-immediate-done` which is bound to `C-M-j` by default after you have typed the name.

Answer (score 1):

For an alternate solution you can set `ivy-use-selectable-prompt`. This will make the prompt selectable like a regular candidate.

Comment: Thank you very much for this little piece of information that I needed! :)
Doom Emacs uses this by default and I couldn't figure it out by myself...