# How to prevent magit with ivy from selecting an author email address?

Tags: magit, ivy

I have a git repository containing commits with 3 of my email addresses. When I try to view the log and filter by author (-A) and then enter a few letters of my last name, I see a list of the 3 email addresses from all commits that match those letters, and I'm forced to select one. I actually just want the 3 letters in the author search that will match all THREE of my email addresses. How I can break out of ivy's autocompletion here, and just use the 3 letters I've entered?

Comment: `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`). See [`(ivy) Key bindings for single selection action then exit minibuffer`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer).

Comment: @Basil Please turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: @tarsius I'd rather close this question as duplicate of one of the following: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/28982/15748 https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/21028/15748 https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35378/15748 https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/39475/15748.

Comment: Works for me too but I never had much success when I suggested that a question be closed. I have pretty much given up on getting enough people to vote to close before the vote times out.